# How do I translate the following the SQL query into a Django API query?

Tags: python, sql, django

```
SELECT "Treatment" FROM car_treatment, input
WHERE car_treatment."Colour" = input."Colour" AND car_treatment."Descrp" = input."Descrp"
```

I have been trying to figure out how to write this simple query but with no avail.  `car_treatment` and `input` represent two different tables.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your models?

Answer (score 0):

You can use django raw query like this:

```
YOUR_MODEL.objects.raw('SELECT "Treatment" FROM car_treatment, input WHERE car_treatment."Colour" = input."Colour" AND car_treatment."Descrp" = input."Descrp"')
```

more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

Or you can do this:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT "Treatment" FROM car_treatment, input WHERE car_treatment."Colour" = input."Colour" AND car_treatment."Descrp" = input."Descrp"')
cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you already have a model for the **car_treatment** and **input** tables, named **CarTreatment** and **Input**. (If you don't you need to generate the models that represent your tables using: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models).  Then you can do as follows:

```
input = Input.objects.get(id=1)
car_treatments = CarTreatment.objects.filter(colour=input.colour, descrp=input.descrp)
```

Then car_treatments contains a set of instances that match your query and you can do something useful with them such as render in a template that gets passes back to user in a response.

```
  {% for treatment in car_treatments %}
  <h1>{{treatment}}</h1>
  <ul>
  <li>{{treatment.descrp}}</li>
  <li>{{treatment.colour}}</li>
  </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```